# Reorder rows of pandas DataFrame according to a known list of values

Tags: pandas

I can think of 2 ways of doing this:

1. Apply `df.query` to match each row, then collect the index of each result
2. Set the column `domain` to be the index, and then reorder based on the index (but this would lose the index which I want, so may be trickier)

However I'm not sure these are good solutions (I may be missing something obvious)

Here's an example set up:

```py
domain_vals = list("ABCDEF")
df_domain_vals = list("DECAFB")
df_num_vals = [0,5,10,15,20,25]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"domain": df_domain_vals, "num": df_num_vals})
```

This gives `df`:

```
  domain  num
0      D    0
1      E    5
2      C   10
3      A   15
4      F   20
5      B   25
```

### 1: Use `df.query` on each row

So I want to reorder the rows according using the values in order of `domain_vals` for the column `domain`.

A possible way to do this is to repeatedly use `df.query` but this seems like an un-Pythonic (un-panda-ese?) solution:

```py
>>> pd.concat([df.query(f"domain == '{d}'") for d in domain_vals])
  domain  num
3      A   15
5      B   25
2      C   10
0      D    0
1      E    5
4      F   20
```

### 2: Setting the column `domain` as the index

```py
reorder = df.domain.apply(lambda x: domain_vals.index(x))
df_reorder = df.set_index(reorder)
df_reorder.sort_index(inplace=True)
df_reorder.index.name = None
```

Again this gives

```py
>>> df_reorder
  domain  num
0      A   15
1      B   25
2      C   10
3      D    0
4      E    5
5      F   20
```

---

Can anyone suggest something better (in the sense of "less of a hack"). I understand that my solution works, I just don't think that calling `pandas.concat` along with a list comprehension is the right approach here.

Having said that, it's shorter than the 2nd option, so I presume there must be some equally simple way I can do this with `pandas` methods I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is `merge`:

```
(pd.DataFrame({'domain':df_domain_vals})
   .merge(df, on='domain', how='left')
)
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the right answer for me, the values for `domain` column are still out of order?